# Executing shell script commands in Ruby script

Tags: ruby, linux, bash

I have a very basic question. I'm running a Ruby script to access the contents of a directory in Linux. The directory is passed through the command line when the ruby script is executed.

My question is how would I use the command line argument in the command for ruby?

I have it set like such:

```
usrDirectory = ARGV[0]
lsCmd = `ls -l`
```

I need to use something like ls -l usrDirectory.
Could I just insert it into the command like is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above is right, and if you want to have `ls` output to standard out, this makes it a little cleaner:

```
system("ls", "-l", dir)
```

This will make Ruby print the output to your standard out instead of putting the output in the variable as the above does.

Comment: If you're going to use `system` you should use the multi-argument version: `system('ls', '-l', dir)`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get what you want without using the shell, for example:

```
usr_dir = "/tmp"
files = Dir["#{usr_dir}/*"]

p files
```

No matter what you do, be **Very Careful** when passing text entered by an user to the shell as part of something that will get parsed and executed. For example, what happens if the user enters (instead of a directory name)

> ;rm -rf /*

?

Comment: That's why you use the multi-argument versions of these commands, they bypass the shell and use your arguments directly as the arguments for the program.

Comment: Yes, the point is don't let the shell parse it. Way too much power.

Comment: Exactly. I'm pretty sure we agree.

Answer (score 0):

You can use expression expansion and escape sequences in the command string:

```
lsCmd = `ls -l #{usrDirectory}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. You can do:

```
lsCmd = `ls -l #{usrDirectory}`
```

or

```
command = "ls -l " + usrDirectory
lsCmd = %x[ #{command} ]
```